# Selenium didn't fill out the form correctly

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### 1. First Case

This is my script, I wanna log in to google using selenium.

```
## ...
driver.get("https://www.smile.one/customer/account/login")
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_name('identifier').send_keys(email + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(mantra + Keys.RETURN)
## ...
```

The script above work properly when I tried on my laptop. The identifier field filled with "exampleemail24" and the password filled with "example24".

However, the script above doesn't work when I use it on VPS (AWS EC2 t3.small 2vCPU 2GB RAM). The identifier fields filled correctly by "exampleemail24" but the password filled by "example".

### 2. Second Case

I tried in another form but I got the same problem.
This is my script.

```
time.sleep(3) userid_form = driver.find_element_by_id('museid')
serverid_form = driver.find_element_by_id('mserverid')
userid_form.send_keys(data['user_id'])
serverid_form.send_keys(data['server_id'] + Keys.SHIFT, Keys.TAB)
```

This is the form.

```
<form id="mpay" action="/merchant/pay" method="post">
    <div class="sectionId-bor">
       <input type="tel" class="sectionId-input" id="museid" placeholder="USER ID" value="">
       <input type="tel" class="sectionId-input" id="mserverid" placeholder="Server ID" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

There are two fields: *userid* and *serverid*. When I tried the script in localhost (my laptop), the script works properly. Filled *userid* with "79100601" and *serverid* with "2149". However,791 when I deployed it on VPS (same VPS with the first case VPS). The *userid* filled with "791006" and *serverid* "012149".

#### Additional

I have **ensured by print the variables that I used and they are correct**.

**Both cases show no error logs.** And also tried to **use selenium wait until and python sleep for 10 seconds**. So, I think not caused by slow internet connection or elements not fully loaded.

Where is the problem? Have you ever experienced this?

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @cheshire both (AWS EC2 and my local laptop) are using Selenium v3.141.0. Also, the same chrome and chromedriver version (87.0.4280).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, it turns out that this problem is caused by VNC that I am using. I don't know the exact problem. However, the error I mentioned above didn't occur and my script was running normally after I install this package:

```bash
sudo apt install tigervnc-xorg-extension tigervnc-viewer
```